# Angular directive with dynamic controller

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to create a panel directive with a dynamic controller and template so that I can display context-sensitive options in my application. For example, clicking edit on a "Font" setting would show the "Font Options".

I can't find much documentation on it but it looks like it's now possible to specify the controller name on a directive using the `name` attribute:

```
app.directive('dynamicPanel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      config: '=dynamicPanel'
    },
    controller: '@',
    name: 'ctrlName'
  };   
});
```

What I was hoping is that given a panel configuration like this:

```
  vm.panel = {
    controller: 'FontCtrl',
    template: 'font.template.html'
  };
```

I could then load the panel like so:

```
<div class="options-panel" 
     ng-if="vm.panel" 
     dynamic-panel="vm.panel" 
     ctrl-name="{{ vm.panel.controller }}" 
     ng-include="vm.panel.template">

</div>
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I get the error `Badly formed controller string`. Also it looks like only the text binding works for the `name` attribute (`@`).

Is there a way to bind the `name` attribute to a dynamic value or an alternative to dynamic controllers in directives.

Comment: Have a look at this jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Pawel_Gerr/y22ZK/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end by embracing the component pattern. By registering my options panels as individual directives with their own controllers it simply became a question of rendering the directive markup e.g. `<font-options/>` and then compiling the "dynamic panel".

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ickkz1GGbDdSbUOUcvfj?p=preview